# How to have a typed random-access read-only array structure

Tags: haxe

Still finding my feet with Haxe and am looking for way to have a array-like read-only collection that I can specify a type for at compile time

So ideally I need something like the following:

```
var collection:Collection<ItemType>;

var item:ItemType = collection[3];//or
var other:ItemType = collection.getAt(3);

//also, it would be good if it was iterable
for (item in collection)
{
//stuff
}
```

So, exactly like an Array, but read only. Would anybody be able to give me a few pointers, please.

Many thanks

Comment: When you say read only, do you mean that it is defined at compile time and cannot be changed?  Or that it is defined by an object and cannot be changed by another object?  Interesting question though :)

Comment: Hi Jason. I mean defined by one object at runtime, which only wants to expose read-only access to another object.

Comment: Ah-ha - class type parameters are probably the key - see http://haxe.org/ref/type_params. I shall post code when I finally compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't have read-only array access as such, but you can do it with methods:

```
class ReadonlyArray<T> {
    var source:Array<T>;
    public function new(source) this.source = source
    inline function get(index) return source[index]
    inline function iterator() return index.iterator()
}
```

The overhead should be barely noticeable.